# Picture in Table View Cell Not Showing

Tags: ios, objective-c

In this project I have absolutely **no code**. In my main.storyboard I have a **TableViewController** with so far **1 cell**. In that one cell I put an **Image View** in, then I selected the certain picture. The cell is **320 (Width) by 44 (Height)**. Everything seems fine in the main.storyboard, however I press run, the app opens but there is **nothing there, only a bunch of lines.**

Any help would be great I will give screenshots to anyone who needs them in order to help me solve this problem. I am using xCode 5.1

Comment: just use cell.imageview.image=[pass your image url]

Comment: Have you bind datasource and implement delegate method with cell identifier?

Comment: what `numberOfRowsInSection:` returns? Check it is `0`.

Comment: Have you connected data source and data delegate from XIB?

Comment: Share your code or atleast screenshot for more clarity ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use either a static tableview that uses predefined cells or (by default) use a dynamic tableview - in that case you have to provide the cells in code by adhering to the tableviews data source protocol. Which you seem to not be doing now.

So, in interface builder, set the tableview to be static and you can build the cells in interface builder and they will be displayed. Make sure you delete the boilerplatecode in table viewcontroller that is given to you to easily implement the protocol (if you don't delete it, the default code returns nil off the cells and so none will get displayed).

When you get it working, find a nice tableview tutorial. I suggest ray wenderlich or the cs193p course on itunesU.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write any code than you must tableView type to static!
Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet for TableViewDelegate. Hope this will help. Don't forget to thumbs up

Make sure you have this in your TableView

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

        return 1;      ---->> should return 1
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return 10;     ----->> return how many rows you want to show, mostly you write 
                               return yourarray.count;
    }


     I think the problem will be in the method below
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        UITableViewCell *cell = nil;            ---->> Instead of UITableViewCell you need to 
                                                       change to the class name of the 
                                                       TableCell ( This is where your cell is 
                                                       created)

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"]; 

        if(!cell){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; ---->>Instead of UITableViewCell you need to 
                                change to the class name of the 
                                TableCell ( This is where your cell is created)
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";

        return cell;
    }
```